# How to make 1 form button to input multiple name and values

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I want to make a form that will have a button.

And when I click the button, different input will be stored for example:
This is for queueing system,
If I click the department button and submit the form, it will automatically store department->name, department->letter and department->number

I have a department and queue database table that has both name,letter and number already. In the queue form. I wanted choose from the deparment, and if I choose a certain button for department, It will automatically store its department name letter and number to the queue table by just choosing the button

````
```<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">

    @foreach ($departments as $department)
        <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg w-25">
            <input type="radio" name="department" value="{{ $department->name}}" sr-only required> 
            {{ $department->name}}
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="letter" value="{{$department->letter}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="number" value="{{$department->number}}">
    @endforeach

</div>


@if ($errors->has('department'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('department') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
</div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array for multiple values, It means that your `name` attributes names will be like that `department[]` & `letter[]` & `number[]`. Also very recommend to use check boxes with multiple values. According to the requirements your code will be like that:

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">

    @foreach ($departments as $department)
        <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg w-25">
            <input type="checkbox" name="department[]" value="{{ $department->name}}" sr-only required> 
            {{ $department->name}}
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="letter[]" value="{{$department->letter}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="number[]" value="{{$department->number}}">
    @endforeach

</div>


@if ($errors->has('department'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('department') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
</div>
```

Comment: I try to copy paste the code but im having some errors.
I have a department and queue database table that has both name,letter and number already.

In the queue form.
I wanted choose from the deparment, and if I choose a certain button for department, It will automatically store its department name letter and number to the queue table by just choosing the button

Comment: We do not understand...In the queue form... Better if you could describe / show your tables too. Also, your given code is incomplete. We should atleast see the submitting part to check.

Comment: @nnn this is my queue datatables

Comment: @nnn
this is my queue datatables 
$table->bigIncrements('id');
 $table->integer('snumber');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email');
$table->string('department');
$table->string('transaction');
$table->string('letter');
$table->integer('number');
$table->string('remarks');
 $table->string('called');
$table->timestamps();

this is my department datatable
   $table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('letter');
$table->integer('number');
$table->timestamps();

the queue's letter and number value is based on the chosen department

Comment: sorry its too messy

Comment: Please give further details. Yes. Messy and we could not understand your exact requirement. May be you can create a working model under a fiddle (with all details) to test and find a solution for you.